# Trivial lemma on real numbers on Coq

Tags: coq

I want to prove following lemma.

```
Require Import Reals.Reals.
Open Scope R_scope.

Lemma trivial_lemma (r1 r2:R) : r1 - (r1 - r2) = r2.
Proof.
rewrite <- Ropp_minus_distr.
rewrite Ropp_plus_distr.
rewrite Ropp_involutive.
rewrite Ropp_minus_distr'.
Abort.
```

I know `Rplus_opp_l`, but I cannot apply it to my goal because of `r2`.

Please tell me your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should know that the automatic tactic `ring` solves this kind of goals autommatically.  In the long run, you should rely on this tactic often if you wish to be productive.

Second, it appears (through `Search`) that the library does not contain many lemmas about subtraction.  In this case, you may have to unfold this operator to end up with a goal that has the more primitive addition and opposite operations.  Here is a sequence of rewrites that does your work.

```
unfold Rminus.
rewrite Ropp_plus_distr.  
rewrite Ropp_involutive.
rewrite <- Rplus_assoc.
rewrite Rplus_opp_r.
rewrite Rplus_0_l.
easy.
```

The fact that the library does not contain basic lemmas like this is an indication that the library designers intend users to rely more on the `ring` tactic.

Comment: Do note that a single `rewrite` can rewrite multiple things: `unfold Rminus. now rewrite Ropp_plus_distr, Ropp_involutive, <- Rplus_assoc, Rplus_opp_r, R_plus_0_l.`